# Error 400 uploading Image data to device with NSURLSessionDataTask

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am attempting to upload a PNG file to a device, using NSURLDataTask and a "POST" request.
However my attempts always conclude with the device returning a 400 HTTP error code in the response.

My Upload code looks like this:

```
-(void)uploadMedia:(NSData*)mediaData withName:(NSString*)name andID:(NSString*)mediaID
```

{
    NSString *urlString;

```
NSString *appToken [self retrieveAppToken];
NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                      appToken, @"km-device-auth",
                      @"application/octet-stream", @"Content-Type",
                      nil];

sessionConfiguration.HTTPAdditionalHeaders = dict;

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];

urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://%@:7788/Media?name=%@&id=%@",_strIP,name,mediaID];

NSLog(@"Attemptive Upload URL:%@",urlString);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];


request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";
request.HTTPBody = mediaData;

NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"My respone:%@:%@",response,data);
}];


[postDataTask resume];
```

}

Comment: 400 means that there is no service at the address/port you are sending to or it doesn't support the service you are requesting.

Comment: Inaddition to what @johnelemans said , ImageViews will only allow you to upload images that are local , inorder to access remote images (like you are doing here ) you need to use SDImage or somekind of a library

Comment: @john elemans - 400 Means bad request. I think that;s the part I'm trying to get right. Basically it expects an octet-stream with the two headers fields I provided. Hmm. I'll keep trying.

Comment: @Anjula 2 - I think you commented on the wrong question. Not doing anything with NSImage nor does anyone need a library to upload an octet-stream to a device.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLVED**
My headers also required a value for "Content-MD5" which was missing.